# How to delete unused images from android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Ctrl+shift+alt+i will list the unused resources but how to delete them ? do we need to delete them manually?
like in eclipse it used to give red error mark on unused resources so that we can delete them directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use Android Lint to detect unused resources.

In Android Studio go to `Analyze > Inspect Code` to perform an static code analysis and safely traverse through your unused resources.

Answer (score 3):

1. click / move into your res folder
2. choose "Refactor" --> "Remove Unused Resources"

Comment: But sometimes it deletes the used resources also